# Foreign key reference disappears on save

Tags: python, django, django-models

In a simple model structure like that:

```py
class News(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('News', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm having a problem when assigning `ForeignKey` "parent" field. Its value disappears when I'm trying to save an object:

```py
>>> news = News(name='TestNews')
>>> book = Book(name='TestBook', parent=news)
>>> news.save()
>>> str(book.parent)
'News object (2)'
>>> book.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: sample_book.parent_id
```

It's there right before saving, but it's gone on save.

It works fine when (re)assigning parent after saving the first object, but in the actual project I need to call `bulk_save` or at least use `transaction.atomic`

```py
>>> news = News(name='TestNews')
>>> news.save()
>>> book = Book(name='TestBook', parent=news)
>>> book.save()
>>> book.parent
<News: News object (3)>
```

The strangest thing is that I'm sure that it worked the other day with the `bulk_save` and there is a lot of similar examples in the docs.

Comment: Under the hoods a foreign key is just the `id` of the related objects. You cannot assign a foreign key to an object that doesn't exist yet in the database (it doesn't have an id!). So yes, you first need to save `news` and then assign it as parent to `book`. Nothing prevents you from wrapping the whole thing in a transaction (including saving `news`) that will rollback if it fails.

Comment: Yes, but `id` is there already after I save the `news`. I can access it by `book.parent.id`.

Comment: sorry, didn't see you're actually saving `news` before saving `book`. This should work. I cannot reproduce your issue, I've just tried, also on SQLite.